# Facebook customize timeline feeds

Tags: facebook, customization, feed, facebook-timeline

Ive been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours now, but where is the configure Story Attachment -> Caption being used? It doest turn up anywhere in the feed items Ive posted, and im struggling to figure out where it fits in.

And a follow up question, is it possible to customize the feed headline?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean? What do you refer to as "feed headline" or "attachment caption"?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. The Story Attachment Layout isn't being used, and my caption is nowhere to be found in the timeline after my custom action is posted. I found an answer on Stack Overflow:

[Timeline Action Layout - No Attachment displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823118/timeline-action-layout-no-attachment-displayed)

It looks like Facebook is doing this on purpose. If this is true, it seems like they should warn you about that in the Configure Story Attachment section.